# Local development enviornment runs fine, but test with Passenger is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My test server setup:

```
Amazon AMI 2013
Ruby interpreter: 2.0.0-p195
Rails 3.2.13
```

Passenger section in httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.7/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.7
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p195/ruby
```

Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV):

```
test
```

In my gemfile, I have the following:

```
gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"
```

and when I verify the gem list on the test server, I see that:

cancan (1.6.10)

Is in there. When I try to run the app, here's what I get:

```
Web application could not be started
Phusion Passenger has listed more information below

git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git (at 2.0) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you run bundle install? do you see installing/using cancan?

Comment: Yes, as I indicated in my question, when I do 'gem list' from a terminal on the test server, cancan (1.6.10) is listed as one of the installed gems.

Comment: From how it looks it seems like it's looking for cancan 2.0 and you have 1.6.10.

Comment: The Gemfile is instructing it to install branch 2.0

Comment: Phusion Passenger should also have told you which user your app is running as. Can you verify whether that is correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by what "user".